# PHP/SQL Activity/News Feed a.k.a Recent Activity Feed

Tags: php, mysql

I need to learn how to create a well-designed PHP "recent activity" feed
which displays the recent activity of users on the site along with their
username, activity, and how long ago they performed that action/activity.
I have no progress so far, any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say no progress... Do you have a site already?

Comment: Yes I have a site, It is a subdomain, I'm getting all the code needed then release it so its not much right now, <a href="http://thecoolest.comuf.com">the site</a>

Answer (score 3):

This is not just a PHP specific problem. Take a look at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture) to understand about the architecture of Activity Feeds.

Also, my suggestion is that activity feeds can be better implemented in PHP using NoSQL based database solutions (like MongoDB, CouchDB) rather than using MySQL.